# localStorage is not assigning key, but instead key has the value data

Tags: angular, angular-local-storage

Angular 6 Project: I'm not able to set key for localStorage and not able to retrive the localstorage data

Can anyone help me with this?

**UserService.service.ts :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class UserService {

authToken;
user;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


addUser(a) {
  return this.http.post('/api/register', a);
}

authUser(data) {
  return this.http.post('/api/login', data);
}

storeUserData(token, user) {
 this.authToken = token;
 this.user = user;
 let akey = localStorage.key('token');
 let bkey = localStorage.key('userData');
 localStorage.setItem(akey, this.authToken);
 localStorage.setItem(bkey, JSON.stringify(this.user));

 //OR

 localStorage.setItem('token', token);
 localStorage.setItem('userData', user);

}

}
```

**User.component.ts :**
The function to trigger the service func

```
loginUser(data) {
this.userService.authUser(data).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data.user);
  if(!data.success) {
    this.authErr = true;
    console.log('Error Occured!');
  } else {
    this.authErr = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    this.userService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
  }
});
}
```

[This is the value I'm having in my localstorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hQKC.png)

Comment: What issue are you seeing?

Comment: Try first `this.userService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user)`, then `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])`.

Comment: did that, still facing the same issue!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hQKC.png

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the value panel covering up the localstorage key/value list?

This is what the local storage list looks like on my PC:

[image]

Notice the horizontal bar in the middle can be clicked and dragged on hover.

In the screen shot you posted, it looks like the lower half panel has been dragged up so it is covering the top half, so you aren't actually looking at the keys. Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your code never gets called. Look at these two lines:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
this.userService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
```

It seems that you navigate away first, then try to store data. What happens if you swap the lines?

Comment: Hi, after swaping the lines I have the same issue,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hQKC.png

Comment: Can you make a Stackblitz that reproduces it? It seems like your key is the value, and then the value is empty. Your second version (`localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))`) should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with

```
localStorage.setItem("userKey", JSON.stringify(this.user));
```

> Make sure `user` is not `null` or `undefined`,